# Need help replacing specific parts of multiple directory names

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I want to use cmd.exe or a batch file to replace a specific string in all directories within one location.

e.g. directory `1900abcd - 1900wxyz` becomes `1700abcd - 1700wxyz`.

The `abcd` and `wxyz` parts of the directory names must stay the same.

I've done lots of looking around, and only seen ways to trim directory names, not replacing characters at specific positions within the name. I have tried structuring a `For` loop for this, but I don't fully understand how to adapt it for this purpose.

Update: some outside input leaves me with this as a working possibility, maybe some help getting this batch file format to work?

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "oldsubstring=old"
set "newsubstring=new"

for /d %%D in (*) do (
   set "folder name=%%D"
   set "newfoldername=!folder name:%oldsubstring%=%newsubstring%!"
   ren "%%D""!newfoldername!"
)

endlocal
```

Comment: We are here to help you with your code, so please show your attempt and explain how it does not what you want.

Comment: I mean, my attempts were simply throwing out errors. I tried `for /d %D in ("directory\*") do ren "%D" "1700???????1700????"` , but I feel that's less helpful for you and more just shows my cluelessness. What I really need is someone to outline what I should be doing here. I'm trying this because it will save me literal hours compared to individually renaming over 1500 folders.

Comment: That's a good start. Assign to a variable (like `set "var=%D" and replace each `1900` with `1700` (see `set /?`). Also read `for /?` to learn that you have to use `%%D` instead of `%D` in a batch script. And finally, take a look at [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028). That should give you enough info to solve your problem My dog wants a walk now, but I'll return, in case you discover more problems.

Comment: Interesting. The documentation `ren /?` from the prompt does not mention directories, only files. Empirically, it appears that `*` and `?` are not allowed in renaming a directory. It would therefore appear necessary to tell us what the patterns are for the source and destination names.

Comment: Hi Magoo, thanks for the input. The exact pattern for renaming things here is that I have a specific number (which is a year indicator) that I need to sub out for another year across all folders. The folders are all formatted like this: `1900abcd-1900wxyz`, where the 1900 is to indicate 2019, and what I really need is to be able to sub out that four number string in BOTH instances of appears in a folder name. i.e. for 1700, for 2017.

Comment: Also, see above for updated possible code, I've had some input but still not working yet.

Comment: I think you just missed a space with the `ren` command to separate the two parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay! The solution! All credit to my brother for this code, where `old` is the string within the folder name you want replacing, and `new` is what it will become. It will change all instances of this string within the name. Saved as a batch file, this will work for every folder in the parent folder they're in.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "oldsubstring=old"
set "newsubstring=new"

for /d %%F in (*) do (
     set "foldername=%%F"
     set "newname=!foldername:%oldsubstring%=%newsubstring%!"
     ren "%%F" "!newname!"
)

endlocal
```